# Android studio no encuentra una dependencia

Tags: java, android

android studio me pide una clase que supuestamente esta dentro de un jar, pero no la encuentra
Tengo un class con los siguientes imports:

```
import com.google.gson.*;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
```

En el build.gradle tengo lo siguiente

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bfhsoftware.sonidoambiental"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
}
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.net.httpserver/http' }
    maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun/tools' }

}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.sun.net.httpserver:http:20070405'
    compile 'com.sun:tools:1.7.0.13'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation files('lib/Sonidoambiental-1.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    compileOnly files('tools-1.7.0.13.jar')
}
```

y me da el siguiente error:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "sun.misc.Service" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
...
```

"sun.misc.service" por lo que tengo entendido pertenece a sun.misc.tools que esta en la dependencias, pero no entiendo porque no lo toma!!
Tengo agregado por maven y el archivo tools-1.7.0.13.jar, no entiendo porque no lo toma, alguien sabe porque puede ser? gracias

Answer (score 1):

Las clases del paquete `sun.*` no deben usarse, Oracle no garantiza su continuidad y han ido siendo reemplazadas.
En tu caso, deberías cambiar `sun.misc.Service` por `java.util.ServiceLoader`.
Por ejemplo, de

```
Iterator<MyServiceProvider> = sun.misc.Service.providers(MyServiceProvider.class);
```

a

```
Iterator<MyServiceProvider> = java.util.ServiceLoader.load(MyServiceProvider.class).iterator();
```

Más información en [esta pregunta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40369019/replacement-class-for-sun-misc-service)

Comment: Pero esto me parece no aplica para android.

Answer (score 1):

Podría asegurarte que las clases de Sun "sun.misc.service" no funcionan con Android.

**No necesitas agregar dependencia alguna, usa la clase [ServiceLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ServiceLoader.html)**:

Agrega el import:

```
import java.util.ServiceLoader;
```

Usa la clase [ServiceLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) :

```
ServiceLoader serviceLoader = ServiceLoader.load(ClaseServicio.class);
```

Comment: solo por chusmear de que va esta clase

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag Hola Bruno a que te refieres? :)

Comment: Queria saber de que iba el tema de esta clase , pero luego de comentar vi que estaba el link a la documentacion Oficial por lo que hagamos de cuenta que no dije nada  ,